# CSS selector for neighbor

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's what I'm working on,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>David Paint</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body { background: linear-gradient(to right, #00e5ff, #00e676); margin: auto; max-width: 736px; font-size: 0px }
            #icons img { width: 36px }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

<span id="icons">
    <a href="david">
        <img title="David" src="david.svg">
    </a>
    <a href="paint">
        <img title="Paint" src="paint.svg">
    </a>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I use **CSS selectors** to target `<img title="Paint" src="paint.svg">` without adding more classes or IDs? The problem arose when I wrapped the `img` tags in `a` tags. Before that, I could target the last `img` tags no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use css selectors for that. like #icons a img{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each of the following ways

1. `#icons img[title = 'paint'] { ... }`
2. `#icons img[src = 'paint.svg']{ ... }`
3. `#icons a:last-child img { ... }`
4. `#icons a:nth-child(2) img { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this, just target the last `a` element instead of the last `img` element.

```
#icons a:last-of-type img {
 /* Your styling here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child()` pseudo-selector

Here `img` is the child of `a` so we need to apply `:nth-child` to `a` and then target `img`. If we want to target image inside first hyperlink(`<a>`) then we need to use `:nth-child(1)`

```
#icons a:nth-child(1) img{
 display:none;
}
```

To target second hyperlink image we need use `:nth-child(2)`

```
#icons a:nth-child(2) img{
     display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuzb8cnm/)

You can refer [this](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) article from csstricks to know more about :nth-child() pseudo-selector

Answer (score 0):

The attribute selector is used to select elements with the specified attribute starting with the specified value.

```
[title~= Paint] {border:1px solid #000}
```

Comment: but then it will apply for all images who are in span. we should use id for particular images, right?

Comment: I improved the answer, this way you can apply the CSS according to the attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last-child()` selector:

```
#icons a:last-child img{
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

Here is fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/eao47zr3/